Issue with Reading Transferred SMS on Android
I transferred around 500 SMS messages from an iPhone to a Samsung device. However, when I try to read them using a content resolver, only 33 random messages are being read, despite all 500 being visible in the messaging app.
I tried transferring the same messages to a Redmi device, and the same issue occurred—only 33 messages were read programmatically.
Also when reading SMS messages that were not transferred (i.e., originally on the Android devices), all messages are read successfully.
private suspend fun retrieveSmsData(
    userId: String,
    contentResolver: ContentResolver
): Resource<String> {
    try {
        val smsInboxCursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,
            arrayOf(
                Telephony.Sms.Inbox.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
                Telephony.Sms.Inbox.ADDRESS,
                Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DATE,
                Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY,
            ),
            null, null, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
        )
        if (smsInboxCursor == null || smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst().not()) {
            return Resource.failed("No sms found")
        }
        val tempSmsList = getAllSms(smsInboxCursor)
        if(tempSmsList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val allDataMap = getAllDateMap(tempSmsList)
            return smsRepository.pushToFirebase(allDataMap, userId).first()
        } else {
            return Resource.failed("No sms found")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("SmsViewModel", "retrieveSmsData: ", e)
        return Resource.failed(e.message.toString())
    }
}

private fun getAllSms(smsInboxCursor: Cursor): MutableList<SmsData> {
    val tempSmsList = mutableListOf<SmsData>()
    val smsCount = smsInboxCursor.count
    for (i in 0 until smsCount) {
        val msgFrom = smsInboxCursor.getString(1)
        val date = smsInboxCursor.getString(2)
        val body = smsInboxCursor.getString(3)
        val formattedDate = Utility().formatDateDDMMYY(date)
        tempSmsList.add(
            SmsData(
                msgFrom = msgFrom,
                timestamp = date,
                msgBody = body,
                formattedDate = formattedDate
            )
        )
        smsInboxCursor.moveToNext()
    }
    return tempSmsList
}

